# Message boxes with Windows 7 look-and-feel

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, windows-7

I reared this MSDN article about customizing design of message boxes:

[User Interface Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa974176.aspx)

and native message boxes looks like this:

[image]

but my messagebox looks like this:

[image]

and here is what I want:

[image]

I'm using C++ and here is my code (the one for confirmation of exit message):

```
int ccm()
{
    int msgbox = MessageBox(
        NULL,
        (LPCWSTR)L"Do you really want to quit?",
        (LPCWSTR)L"Music",
        MB_ICONQUESTION  | MB_YESNO | MB_DEFBUTTON2
    );

    switch (msgbox)
    {
        case IDYES:
            initdw();
            break;
        case IDNO:
            adw();
            break;
    }

    return msgbox;
}
```

I call the ccm(); when the user want to exit and I detect it like that

```
case WM_CLOSE:
    ccm();
    return 0;
```

but I want the code that looks like original windows style
I don't want to design custom messages I want native code

Comment: I think many of the examples you show are not standard message boxes, they're custom windows that have been designed to be similar to the standard.

Comment: well the Paint, Wordpad, Speech Recognition are native

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The kind of customization you are looking for can be achieved by using [`TaskDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760540.aspx) or [`TaskDialogIndirect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760544.aspx), instead of `MessageBox()`.  They are the preferred message box functions on Vista and later versions of Windows, because they are more flexible and they make more use of standardized Windows UI elements for a more consistent look with other UIs.

For example:

```
TaskDialog(hMyWnd, hInstance, L"Music", L"You have the latest version of Music", NULL, TDCBF_OK_BUTTON, MAKEINTRESOURCE(MY_MUSIC_ICON_ID), NULL);
```

```
int iBtn = IDNO;
if (TaskDialog(hMyWnd, NULL, L"Music", L"Do you really want to quit?", NULL, TDCBF_YES_BUTTON | TDCBF_NO_BUTTON, NULL, &iBtn) == S_OK)
{
    switch (iBtn)
    {
        case IDYES:
            initdw();
            break;
        case IDNO:
            adw();
            break;
    }
}
```